# Mouseover text for Careers 2.0 profile "add" links is missing a space

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The mouseover text on some links on the *My profile* editing page for the Careers 2.0 site is incorrect.  Links for *add experience*, *add education* and *add certification* have mouseover text of the form *Add a new item underXXX* where *XXX* is the item to be added and there is no space between that word and the word *under*

e.g. the *add experience* mouseover is "Add a new item underExperience":

[image: "add experience" tooltip with missing space]

The strings are being set under the < a > *title* attribute so it's probably due to concatenation with a variable in the page generation server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved, please have another look?

Comment: works for me: there's mouseover text displayed ""Add a new item under Experience"